# cmdLog.Paramerters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rr",button2.text);

Tags: c#

i want to pass the value of button to "@rr" in C# is it correct?

Comment: You should edit and clarify your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746944

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
cmdLog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rr", button2.text);
```